# A more intuitive way to classify $(\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z})/\langle (2, 2) \rangle$?

Tags: group-theory, quotient-group

After reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720900/classifying-the-factor-group-mathbbz-times-mathbbz-langle-2-2-ran) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721523/smith-normal-form-and-classification-of-factor-groups-according-to-the-theorem-o) and I’m wondering if there’s a shorter and more intuitive way: would it be correct to claim the following?

By change of basis to $(1,0), (1,1)$ we can write
\begin{align*}
  (\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}) / \langle (2, 2) \rangle
  &\cong
  \Bigl( \langle (1,0) \rangle \oplus \langle (1,1) \rangle \Bigr)
  \Big/
  \Bigl( \langle (0,0) \rangle \oplus \langle (2,2) \rangle \Bigr) \\
  &\cong
  \Bigl( \langle (1,0) \rangle \big/ \langle (0,0) \rangle \Bigr)
  \oplus
  \Bigl( \langle (1,1) \rangle \big/ \langle (2,2) \rangle \Bigr) \\
  &\cong
  \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2
\end{align*}
where the first isomorphism is by change of basis for $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and the second is by the fact that the quotient of direct sums of abelian groups is the direct sums of the quotients since $\langle (0,0) \rangle$ and $\langle (2,2) \rangle$ are subgroups of the respective groups in the product (as seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272898/about-direct-sum-of-abelian-groups-and-quotient)).

If not – is there a similar way to state this? I find these transitions more intuitive than the Smith normal form or finding appropriate isomorphisms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on how comfortable you are with group presentations.

One way to write $G=\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$ is as the group given by the presentation

$$G\cong\langle a,b\mid ab=ba\rangle$$

and the subgroup $H=\langle (2,2)\rangle$ can then be written as the normal subgroup $\langle (ab)^2\rangle$ generated by $(ab)^2$ (because you can think of $a$ as $(1,0)$ and $b$ as $(0,1)$). Now

$$\begin{align}
G/H&\cong \langle a,b\mid ab=ba\rangle/\langle (ab)^2\rangle\\
&\cong\langle a,b\mid (ab)^2, ab=ba\rangle\\
&\cong\langle a,b,c\mid (ab)^2, ab=ba, c=ab\rangle\\
&\cong\langle a,b,c\mid c^2, c=ba, b=a^{-1}c\rangle\\
&\cong\langle a,c\mid c^2, c=(a^{-1}c)a\rangle\\
&\cong\langle a,c\mid c^2, ac=ca\rangle\\
&\cong \Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z_2
\end{align}$$

by Tietze transformations.

Comment: Thanks - so, just to clarify, is my method incorrect? If so - where did I go wrong?

Comment: You're welcome, @Anon. Yes, your method seems fine.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer, @Anon, by clicking the $\checkmark$ symbol.